# Access private array of pointers to objects from a method in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers, new-operator

I'm not sure really what to search for to try and find my answer, so please redirect me to any relevant articles and I apologize in advance.

I'm really new to C++ and am trying to make a 3x3 CLI Tile game. I can assign the Tile objects to the private array of pointers in the TileGame constructor and see they have valid memory addresses (or so I think.) My problem is when I run a method to try and access that data. It looks like the the first element in the array has a value, but the others look very odd. I'm sure it's something small, but I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong. I've also tried creating an accessor method, but that only seemed to complicate things.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Tile
{
    private:
        int position;
        int tileID;
    public:
        Tile(int, int);
};

// tile constructor
Tile::Tile(int p, int id) : position(p), tileID(id) {}

class TileGame
{
    private:
        const int MAX_TILES;
        Tile* tiles[];
    public:
        TileGame();
        void shuffle();
};

// game constructor
TileGame::TileGame() : MAX_TILES(8)
{
    Tile* tiles[MAX_TILES];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TILES; i++)
    {
        tiles[i] = new tile(i, i);
    }

    // spit out the addresses for each
    cout << endl << "From TileGame(): " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TILES; i++)
    {
        cout << tiles[i] << endl;
    }
}

void TileGame::shuffle()
{
    // spit out the addresses for each
    cout << endl << "From TileGame(): " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TILES; i++)
    {
        cout << tiles[i] << endl; // <-- This seems to be the problem
    }
}

int main()
{
    TileGame* game = new TileGame();
    game->shuffle();
}
```

This should compile (I had to retype it, so I hope I didn't make mistakes.) The output that I get is something like:

```
From TileGame():
0x7f9349c03aa0
0x7f9349c03ab0
0x7f9349c03ac0
0x7f9349c03ad0
0x7f9349c03ae0
0x7f9349c03af0
0x7f9349c03b00
0x7f9349c03b10

From shuffle():
0x7fff9502752c
0x100
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I arrived at this point when I kept getting seg faults by trying to access `tiles[]` values. Thoughts?

Comment: if you are allocating 8 size to the 2d array, why not declare it in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tiles` array that is created in the constructor of `TileGame` is not the `tiles` array in the `Game` object. Get rid of the one in the constructor.

Also, too may pointers. The `tiles` array can hold `Tile` objects; no need for the indirection and the `new`s. Similarly, there's no need for `game` to be a pointer. Just create it as a `TileGame` object.

Comment: To put `Tile` objects rather than pointers in the array, you'd have to make `Tile` default-constructible, or change the array to a vector and emplace them into it. I'm not sure which would be the lesser evil.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - yes, it would require a default constructor. That's far better than the Java-style usage here.

Comment: Ah, so it was (initially) a scope issue with the constructor array. I suppose I was thinking that I needed to some how set the maximum number of elements.

Comment: @jktravis - well, you do need to set the size of the array. Unless it's going to vary at runtime, it should probably be `Tile *tiles[MAX_TILES];` or, my preference, `Tile tiles[MAX_TILES];`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Where would I set this? I was thinking the constructor, but that was obviously incorrect.

Comment: At the point where it's declared in the class definition. Change `Tile *tiles[]` to one of the two alternatives that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

Your constructor is not doing anything to initialise the member called `tiles`; instead it's populating a local array of the same name. This is discarded, leaking the allocated memory, when the constructor exits. Then you get undefined behaviour (in your case, a segmentation fault) when you try to use the uninitialised member.

The member should be a pointer, rather than an array, if you don't know the size at compile time:

```
Tile ** tiles;
```

allocated like:

```
tiles = new Tile* [MAX_TILES];
```

Remember to delete each tile (`delete tiles[i]`), and the array itself (`delete [] tiles`) in the destructor; and as always when managing resources yourself, remember the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Better still, use `std::vector` so you don't have to manage the memory yourself. In general, you should avoid dynamic allocation when you don't need it; for example, the `TileGame` you create in `main` could be an automatic variable (`TileGame game;`) to fix the memory leak you have there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm not quite sure I understand exactly what or how to apply these, though. Removing the constructor `tiles[]` does produce the results that I was expecting. Clearly, I have a ways to go.